# Javascript for loops with negative numbers

Tags: javascript, loops

Can anyone tell me why these javascript loops don't run?

```
for(var i = -5; i == 0; i++) {
    document.write(i);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0h2p6uod/

```
for(var i = -5; i == -1; i++) {
    document.write(i);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xb4k0sub/

```
for(var i = -5; i == 5; i++) {
    document.write(i);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4bbatja9/

And yet, all of these loops run:

```
for(var i = -5; i < 0; i++) {
    document.write(i);
}

for(var i = -5; i < -1; i++) {
    document.write(i);
}

for(var i = -5; i < 5; i++) {
    document.write(i);
}
```

Comment: OK, remind me what's the _second_ thing in the loop initialisation? That `i == 0` what does it do? Why do _you_ think it doesn't work?

Comment: condition should only be false for loop end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for loop has 4 main parts:

```
for (initializer; condition; postoperation) {
    body;
}
```

It is equivalent to

```
initializer;
while (condition) {
    body;
    postoperation;
}
```

In your first example,

```
for(var i = -5; i == 0; i++) {
    document.write(i);
}
```

the condition is `i == 0`, so the loop will only continue when `i` is 0. But in the initializer, you set `i` to `-5`, so it stops immediately. If you change `i == 0` to `i != 0`, it will continue as long as `i` is not 0, so it will stop when it reaches 0. You can do something similar for the other loops.

Answer (score 4):

The condition part is testing for `true`. If `false`, the loop stops.

[`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

> **condition**
>
> An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration. If this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed. This conditional test is optional. If omitted, the condition always evaluates to true. If the expression evaluates to false, execution skips to the first expression following the for construct.

```
for(var i = -5; i == 0; i++) {
//              ^^^^^^  false -> no loop
```